# WordPress плагин WpGlobus вывод статей

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-plugin

такая ситуация, есть блог WP на 2-х языках RU | EN. установлен плагин для мультиязычности WpGlobus(бесплатный!). Я загружаю статьи через API сразу c 2-х источников(RU | EN) в базу согласно с разметкой плагина только по одному языку, типа: {:en}Title{:} или {:ru}Title{:}. Мне нужно выводить записи, если она залита с  EN источника то только в если пользователь находиться на странице с флажком языка EN, и вообще не выводить их при включенном флажке RU и наоборот, заранее благодарен

Comment: Переведи этот поток сознания на нормальный технический русский язык. И убери инфомусор.

Comment: мне нужно что бы плагин WpGlobus не выводил посты на главной странице если на них нет перевода

Comment: Под твоим потоком мыслей есть ссылка "править".  Воспользуйся ей и приведи вопрос в порядок. Глядишь и шансы получить ответ возрастут. *Хотя я не знаю кто бы пользовался этим плагом*.

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста - решил ли данную проблему ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В платном расширении [WPGlobus Plus](https://wpglobus.com/ru/extensions/wpglobus-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81/) есть возможность объявлять статус "черновик" для конкретного языка в посте.

Но в вашем случае, мне кажется, что можно разделить посты на категории. Или метки вести. Если каждый из постов написан только на одном языке, то разделение Глобусом не оптимально.